# When printing a WEB-page with custom CSS the output is not as good as in the browser

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extensions, print-to-pdf

I am using custom CSS to format a Wikipedia Webpage and trying to convert it into PDF.
Irrespective of the add-on, e.g. *User JavaScript and CSS* or *Stylish*, the result in the browser looks very nice and neat, but when I call the Print Dialog Box, the styling of fonts and paragraphs is no longer that coherent. My aim is to attain a good layout for printing into a PDF file.

The CSS code is below, although however, I fiddle with it, it always produces different results in the Browser and in the Print Dialog Box, and, hence, in the PDF.

```
@media all {

body {
    padding: 0 0%;
    font-family: jaf-bernino-sans, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    zoom: 100%;
}
 
p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.08px;
    line-height: 18px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
 
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: jaf-bernino-sans, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
 
h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: jaf-bernino-sans, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
 
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: jaf-bernino-sans, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
 
div {
    font-family: jaf-bernino-sans, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

li {
    font-family: jaf-bernino-sans, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.08px;
}
 
.pBody li {
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
 
.pBody {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.ambox {
    display: none;
}

.vector-body {
    font-size: 14px;
    /*font-size: calc(1em * 0.875);*/
}
 
#firstHeading {
    margin: 50px 50px 0;
}
 
#bodyContent {
    margin: 0 10px; 
}
 
#content {
    font-family: freight-text-pro, Georgia, Cambria, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    /*border-right: 1px solid #999;*/
}
 
#p-personal li {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
}

#footer {
    display: none;
}

#toc {
    display: none;
}
}
```

A Browser view sample:

[image: A browser sample]

A Print Dialog Sample:

[image: A print dialogue sample]

My OS is Windows 11. Chrome version 106.0.5249.119 (64-bit.) Standard Windows PDF print driver.

Comment: Wikipedia is sure to have a print stylesheet. Make sure it’s not overriding/interacting with your in an undesirable way.

Comment: Is turning it into an image, and embedding the image in a PDF an option?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I understand and override it, which is proven by the layout in the Browser.

Comment: @Gantendo I do not feel it is worth going to such great lengths, probably there is a simpler solution

Comment: @PavloMaistrenko While _browsing_, print stylesheets are, per definition, _not_ active. In print preview, they are. You can use Developer Tools to toggle it anytime.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you very much, I am trying out the print emulation feature of the Chrome DevTools (*three vertical dots ⁝* in the right corner, *More Tools* menu, *Rendering* item.) And I can see that the print emulation indeed differs from the normal WEB view. Need some time to study deeper

Comment: So, the solution is twofold: a. Along with `@media all {}` section in the custom CSS, I have created `@media print {}` with the same styles. b. I have checked the _Highest CSS priority_ checkbox in the formatting extension menu. Thank you very much for your help!